# Show Props Data into the Dialog Box in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

Am new to React JS and i am Developing some sample eCommerce based application as my realtime application so i am stuck with one issue.

In Products List there is Buy button, If i click on the button one dialog box should pop with respective product details

I wrote two components one is ProductCard and DialogImage Components

am showing list of products in ProductCard here is the code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import axios from "axios";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { Container } from "@material-ui/core";
import DialogImage from "../pages/DialogImage";



export default function ProductCard(props) {
 const classes = useStyles();
 const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

const fetchProducts = () => {
axios.get("http://images.stockal.com/api/products.json").then(response => {
  console.log(response.data);
  setProducts(response.data.data.products);
});
};

useEffect(() => {
 fetchProducts();
}, []);

const [openModal, setModal] = useState(false);
const [image, setImage] = useState('');
const [size, setSize] = useState('');

function selectedproduct(searchImage, sizes) {
  setModal(true);
  setImage(searchImage);
  setSize(sizes);
}

return (
<div className={classes.root}>
  <Container>

    <DialogImage modal={openModal} productImage={image} productSize={size}  />
    <Grid container spacing={6}>
      {products.map((event, index) => {
        return (
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={4} key={index}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
              <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs={5}>
                  <img
                    src={event.searchImage}
                    alt={event.product}
                    width="100%"
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={7}>
                  <Box fontWeight="fontWeightBold" m={1}>
                    {event.productName}
                  </Box>
                  <Box m={1}> Price: Rs. {event.price} \- </Box>
                  <Box m={1}> Brand: {event.brand} </Box>
                  <Box m={1}> Sizes: {event.sizes} </Box>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                fullWidth
                color="primary"
                onClick={selectedproduct.bind(
                  this,
                  event.searchImage,
                  event.sizes
                )}
              >
                Buy
              </Button>
            </Paper>
          </Grid>
        );
      })}
    </Grid>
  </Container>
</div>
);}
```

and DialogImage Component

```
export default function DialogImage(props) {
console.log(props);
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const [image, setImage] = useState("");
const [size, setSize] = useState("");

const handleClickOpen = () => {
setOpen(true);
setImage(props.productImage);
setSize(props.productSize);
};

const handleClose = () => {
setOpen(false);
setImage("");
setSize("");
};

return (
<div>
  <Dialog
    open={open}
    onClose={handleClose}
    aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog-title"
  >
    <DialogTitle style={{ cursor: "move" }} id="draggable-dialog-title">
      Product Name:
    </DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent>
      <DialogContentText>
        <img src={image} alt="Product Name" width="100%" />
        <Box>Product Size: {size}</Box>
      </DialogContentText>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
      <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
        Cancel
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
        Subscribe
      </Button>
    </DialogActions>
  </Dialog>
</div>
);}
```

[image]

Here is the Image when i executed the code, 
am sending data as props to the DialogImage Component as you can see the console above posted image but i am not getting how to trigger or open the Modal Pop up from the ProductCard Component
Please can you help me in this

**as am new beginner to React**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to have opening, closing logic and the `isDialogOpen` state both inside and outside of the Dialog. Just maintain your Dialog's `open`, `close` handlers and `isOpen` state inside `ProductCard` component.

```
const handleDialogOpen = () => {
   setOpen(true);
   setImage(props.productImage);
   setSize(props.productSize);
 };

const handleDialogClose = () => {
   setOpen(false)
   setImage(null)
   setSize(null)
};

...
<DialogImage open={openModal} onClose={handleDialogClose} productImage={image} productSize={size}  />
```

Then inside your `<DialogImage/>` component,

```
export default function DialogImage(props) {
   //you don't need state in here
    return <Dialog
             open={props.open}
             onClose={props.onClose}
             aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog-title">
```